# Is there an easy way to tell if a Java project is written from i.e. NetBeans or Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

Is there an easy way to tell if a Java project is written in a specific IDE? Seems to me like Java projects made by a specific IDE will not be totally transparent to another IDE so it is important to know beforehand which IDE the project was created with.

Regards.

Comment: Java is Java.  The IDE should be totally irrelevant.

Comment: Are you asking about the source or the JAR?

Comment: His question is not confusing and very relevant. If you were to inherit a Java project from someone else, it is possible they never setup build files and completely relied on the IDE. Hence, it could be important to know if the project is from NetBeans or Eclipse, etc.

Comment: Once I had a hard time importing a Java project to Eclipse because it was made on NetBeans before.  I should probably look more into that now..

Comment: The code is going to be transparent.  The IDE will add its own special files to help make its language specific functoinality work, but there's no reason to SLaks point you can't take the source files and move em from one IDE to another.  Also, if you're considering major IDE's used by java devs you'd have to include IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @gview It was included in 'etc.' And Java is not transparent. Nothing inherent in Java specifies how to build the MANIFEST, Sign the JAR, which resources to include, any special compile flags. I could go on. Let's not mix the ubiquitous Ant with Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse projects save out `.project` and `.classpath`

NetBeans saves out `.nbproject`

IntelliJ can use file-based `.iws, .ipr and .iml` or directory based `.idea`

Answer (score 5):

If it is an eclipse project it will have a .project file in the root directory.  If it is a netbeans project you will find a nbproject folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 4):

If the project is using something like ant, maven, ivy (or other sort of build tool), then it'd be portable across IDEs. Most build tools come with plugins or commands to generate IDE specific metadata for the project. (`mvn eclipse:eclipse, play eclipsify, sbt gen-idea...`)

That said, IDE does not really matter - all you need is the source files, dependencies and the compiler at the end of the day.

However if you're checking out of a version control system (svn, git, et.al.), and if the things are done right you will not see any IDE specific files checked in.

Comment: I cannot agree less with your last paragraph.  If you standardized for specific IDE it makes a LOT of sense to check in that IDE's project files.  Build tools ( ant, maven ) should not care about them, and you will not have to spend hours/days restoring your project settings if you've spilled coffee on/dropped your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check the extra configuration files created by the various IDEs. On eclipse, you will find a directory called .metadata at the root of the workspace (not root of the project). It will have a file called .log containing visible information like:

```
!SESSION 2011-03-31 17:24:25.570 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
```

So you can easily see its eclipse. If that directory is not available (lets say not committed with the source code) you can still go to directories inside the project structure and find other meta data in files.

In my project there was a folder called .settings inside the actual project directory tree having files named: `org.eclipse.jdt.core` etc. By simply looking at this you can tell its Eclipse.

I am sure you will find similar clues when you look at a NetBeans project.